# Viz: How to Affine Transform a Point3D with R & T vectors?

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, vtk, opencv3.0

I'm trying to simulate the movement of camera in 3D using OpenCV Viz module. I want to find the Location of a Camera in 3D in the world coordinates! I specify the pose of the camera like this!

How can I get the Location of the camera from the pose "Affine3d "? Note that the Origin is located at Point3d(0,0,0). Do I need to compute this manually? If yes How to transform the Point?

```
    Mat RotationVector(1,3,CV_64FC1,Scalar(0.0));
    Mat TranslationVector(3,1,CV_64FC1,Scalar(1.0));
    Affine3d AffineTransform= Affine3d(RotationVector,TranslationVector);

    cout << "RotationVector: \n"        << RotationVector <<endl;
    cout << "TranslationVector: \n "    << TranslationVector <<endl;
    cout << "AffineTransform: \n"       << AffineTransform.matrix <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Figured it out! You can directly multiply with the Point3d to transform the point like this.

```
Point3d Pt3D_Camera(0.0,0.0,0.0),
            Pt3D_Origin(0.0,0.0,0.0);
Mat RotationVector(1,3,CV_64FC1,Scalar(0.0));
Mat TranslationVector(3,1,CV_64FC1,Scalar(1.0));
Affine3d AffineTransform= Affine3d(RotationVector,TranslationVector);

Pt3D_Camera= AffineTransform* Pt3D_Origin;

cout << "RotationVector: \n"        << RotationVector <<endl;
cout << "TranslationVector: \n "    << TranslationVector <<endl;
cout << "AffineTransform: \n"       << AffineTransform.matrix <<endl;           
cout << "Pt3D_Camera: \n"           << Pt3D_Camera <<endl;
```